# Merge sub-queries to a single query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to merge the nested **MYSQL** queries into one

First of all I fire this query

```
select names , 
       city , 
       category 
from names_data 
group by names , city ,category ;
```

this produces a result of ~28000 from master `names_data` table

now for each entry in the result
I fire this query inside a python loop

```
select date, 
       name, 
       city , 
       old_mul, 
       new_mul 
from name_changes 
where name=' + name + ' 
and city=' + city + """'
order by date desc limit 2 ;
```

I just want the last 2 records date wise for each name and city combination from this `name_changes` table

I have tried few JOINS and groups operation but was not able to achieve what this

Right Now I have 1 + 28000*1 queries

**I want to reduce the queries**

Help is really appreciated :)

p.s. the tables are different

Comment: What's with all the single and triple quotes? Are these in your data or it's how you construct the query in python?

Comment: Yay for SQL Injection...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
-- Query every name_changes where rownum <= per group limit (2)
select * from (
    -- subquery for attaching rownumber counter for `name:city` groups
    select `date`, name, city , old_mul, new_mul, 
        case when @lag != concat(name, ':', city) then @rownum:=1 else @rownum:=@rownum+1 end as rownum, 
        @lag:=concat(name, ':', city)
    from name_changes,
    -- init values
    (select @rownum:=0) init_rownum, 
    (select @lag:=null) init_la
    order by name, city, d desc
) numbered
where rownum <= 2;
```

I had a previous answer about mimicking `window functions` in mysql: [How do I write this query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126630/how-do-i-write-this-query/126655#126655) where I explained this in more details.